# Can serde deserialize XML with flat key value pairs?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I am using the [serde-xml-rs](https://crates.io/crates/serde-xml-rs) crate. I have XML with the following format:

```xml
<data>
   <key>version</key>
   <int>4</int>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>John</string>
</data>
```

Is it possible to parse this into a struct like this?

```rust
enum Node {
  #[serde(rename="int")]
  Int(u32),
  #[serde(rename="string")]
  String(String),
}
struct Data {
  // what serde attributes to use???
  version: Node,
  name: Node,
}
```

I did only manage to parse this into a `Vec` of tuples:

```rust
#[serde(rename = "$value")]
data: Vec<(String, Node)>,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to do what you want to with the `Deserialize` derive macro. However, you can still achieve your goal: Serde allows you to [manually implement `Deserialize`](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html) for cases like this where the derive macro is not powerful enough.

If your code needs to be high performance, you probably want to implement `Deserialize` completely by hand; otherwise, you could also deserialize to a tuple first like you did above and then build your `Data` struct from that. That would be easier as you don't need to interface with the `Deserializer` directly, but also probably not as performant as doing it completely by hand because of the intermediate data representation.

A solution utilizing the intermediate tuple representation is below.

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, Debug)]
enum Node {
  #[serde(rename="int")]
  Int(u32),
  #[serde(rename="string")]
  String(String),
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data {
  version: Node,
  name: Node,
}

impl<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de> for Data {
    fn deserialize<D: serde::Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        use serde::de::Error;
        #[derive(serde::Deserialize, Debug)]
        struct IntermediateResult {
            #[serde(rename = "$value")]
            data: Vec<(String, Node)>,
        }

        // first, deserialize to the tuple via the macro generated Serialize implementation
        let intermediate_result: IntermediateResult = IntermediateResult::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        // find the keys we are looking for and save the values
        let mut version: Option<Node> = None;
        let mut name: Option<Node> = None;
        for key_value_pair in intermediate_result.data {
            let value_to_assign: &mut Option<Node> = match &*key_value_pair.0 {
                "version" => &mut version,
                "name" => &mut name,
                _ => {
                    // handle unknown <key> – either ignore it or return an error; I am going to ignore it
                    continue;
                }
            };
            *value_to_assign = Some(key_value_pair.1);
        }

        // if the required keys are missing, fail
        if version.is_none() {
            return Err(D::Error::custom("Did not find a <key> with content \"version\""));
        }
        if name.is_none() {
            return Err(D::Error::custom("Did not find a <key> with content \"name\""));
        }

        // otherwise, build Data struct
        Ok(Data {
            version: version.unwrap(),
            name: name.unwrap()
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let xml = r###"
        <data>
            <key>version</key>
            <int>4</int>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>John</string>
        </data>
   "###;
   
   let data: Data = serde_xml_rs::from_str(xml).unwrap();
   
   println!("{:?}", data);
}
```